# include sql result in mail

Tags: php, sql

i want include the sql result into a variable for send an mail with a  html who contain values.
When i test my code, the  contain only one line. How i can all  obtain ?
My code is here :

```
<?php
$connect = mysql_connect("*****","********","********");
                mysql_select_db("********", $connect);
                    $req = "SELECT * FROM servers WHERE owner_mail = '******'";
                    $resultat = mysql_query($req);
                    echo "<table border='1'>";
                    echo "<tr><th>Serveur</th><th>Environnement</th><th>Status</th><th>Appli</th></tr>";
                    while ($ligne = mysql_fetch_row($resultat)) {
                    $content = "<tr><td>$ligne[1]</td><td>$ligne[3]</td><td>$ligne[4]</td><td>$ligne[19]</td></tr>";
$pseudo = ($ligne[21]);
$commentaire = ($ligne[1]);
$email = ($ligne[23]);
                }
                    echo "</table>";
     $headers ='From: "nom"<no-reply@gmail.com>'."\n";
     $headers .='Reply-To: ****************'."\n";
     $headers .='Content-Type: text/html; charset="iso-8859-1"'."\n";
     $headers .='Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit';

?>
<html><head></head><body>
<img src='images/logo.jpg' alt='' /></body></html>
<?php
echo "$commentaire<br>";
echo "$email<br>";
echo "$pseudo<br>";

$message .= "Hello\r\n$pseudo,<br>Here you can find the status migration :<br>\r\n<table border='1'><tr><th>Serveur</th><th>Environnement</th><th>Appli</th><th>Status</th></tr>$content</table><br><br> Thanks !";
$message .= "<img src='**********************' alt='' />";

     if(mail($email, 'Status migration', $message, $headers))
     {
          echo 'Le message a été envoyé';
     }
     else
     {
          echo 'Le message n\'a pu être envoyé';
     }
?>
```

Thanks for helper

Comment: Your headers will not work because it is only delimited by `\n`.

Comment: Also you are overwriting `$content` instead of appending.

Comment: where is the problem exactly? more and more people post files of code instead of piece of code with problem, please explain clearly where is the actual problem. Your problem should be separated like:1.email body issue OR 2.string creation issue OR 3.how do i do this.

Comment: @RotariRadu Most the time people don't know where their problem/error is; so they dump the entire file's content on SO :)

Answer (score 2):

Replace this:

```
while ($ligne = mysql_fetch_row($resultat)) {
                    $content = "<tr><td>$ligne[1]</td><td>$ligne[3]</td><td>$ligne[4]</td><td>$ligne[19]</td></tr>";
$pseudo = ($ligne[21]);
$commentaire = ($ligne[1]);
$email = ($ligne[23]);
                }
```

with:

```
$content = '';
while ($ligne = mysql_fetch_row($resultat)) {
                    $content .= "<tr><td>$ligne[1]</td><td>$ligne[3]</td><td>$ligne[4]</td><td>$ligne[19]</td></tr>";
$pseudo = ($ligne[21]);
$commentaire = ($ligne[1]);
$email = ($ligne[23]);
                }
```

In your code, you were overwriting the `$content` variable.

If you want to append data, instantiate the variable outside the loop and append contents using the `.=` operator.